# HttpResponse error during ajax post request in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Friends, I am trying to handle form submission using ajax in django. I've been getting this error which says,

```
The view auths.change_profile.change_username didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here's my change_profile.py

```
def change_username(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request,"auths/edits/edit_username.html",{})
    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        username = request.POST['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user.username = username
        user.save()
        if user.save():
            data = "Username successfully updated"
        else:
            data = "Something went wrong!"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data':data}), content_type="application/json")
```

and my ajax.js is as follows

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#username_form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/change_username/',
        data:{
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#username').html(data);
        }
    });
});
);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you need to change the ordering of your original `if` statements. Technically, the request is ajax, so it's going to return the first if statement. It won't execute the second one. That's my belief anyway. Try putting a `print` statement in there to check.

Comment: i added the check for GET request, but still i am getting the same error. While the GET is doing fine with ajax, there's this problem with POST

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return render(request,"auths/edits/edit_username.html",{})
```

You don't need it, as technically your Ajax request will also be of POST or GET type.
So all you need is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user.username = username
    user.save()
    if user.save():
        data = "Username successfully updated"
    else:
        data = "Something went wrong!"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data':data}))
else:
    json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"})
```

Comment: i think you need to take a look at your answer. do you think there's any curly braces for python control statements?

Comment: My bad, i saw the javascript code and read it as your python code.
Apologies for the error.
Did the solution work for you?

Comment: I've edited my answer, carefully this time. Try it. It should work this time.
See my views.py snippet of handling an AJax request of POST type here -> https://github.com/amyth/hammer/blob/master/apps/overseer/views.py
Go to the "addnew_inst_form_submit()" function in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def change_username(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "auths/edits/edit_username.html", {})
    elif request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user.username = username
        user.save()
        if user.save():
            data = "Username successfully updated"
        else:
            data = "Something went wrong!"
        return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Post Django 1.7, using `JsonResponse` is the recommended format. Pre 1.7 was the method you originally used.

Let me know if that works.

**Edit (attempt 2):**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def change_username(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return render(request, "auths/edits/edit_username.html", {})
    else:
        new_username = request.POST.get('username')
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
        initial_username = user.username
        user.username = new_username
        user.save()

        data = {}

        if user.username == new_username:
            data['data'] = "Username successfully updated!"
        else:
            data['data'] = "Something went wrong!"

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: @amankarn See if my new code works. If not, it's definitely not the view